# How do I compare times in microsoft access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a column title start_time that is stored such as 12:30. I would like to delete a row if it contains 0:00 as the time, but I have not been successful with this yet. Here is my code for a reference.

```
DELETE *
FROM course_times
WHERE start_time IS NULL
OR start_time = '0:00';
```

Also, is there anyway in microsoft access that I can run sql in a window with out having to have it listed as a query and save it? thanks.

Comment: Is `start_time` text containing only the time? Or is is a datetime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delimit dates and/or times with `#` symbols, i.e.:

```
DELETE *
FROM course_times
WHERE start_time IS NULL
OR start_time = #0:00#;
```

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, @Monty Wild gives the obviously correct answer.

To your second question, I'm not sure exactly what you mean by running SQL 'in a window' so I will lay out several options:

- You can just create a new query and, without saving it, switch to SQL view, type in your SQL code and execute it. This lets you run one statement at a time.
- You can open up the VBA window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>), bring up the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>), then type in a SQL statement (DDL statements only) inside a VBA command: `currentproject.connection.execute "delete * from tblTable where ID = 8751"`
- You can write up a small VBA proc that reads in a given file, separates all text in the file using `;` as the separator character, then uses the above-mentioned `Execute` method to carry out the SQL statements one at a time. Then you can create SQL scripts in your favourite editor outside Access, separate each statement with a semi-colon, and have Access run those scripts. You can imagine this is quite powerful.